# return last word in a file that starts with capital letter

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple script that seraches for a designated .txt file for the last word that starts with a capital letter and returns it. If there are no words that start with a capital letter, it returns an empty string.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def find_last_capitalised(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        for word in word_list:
            if word.rfind(upper):
                return word
            else:
                return " "
```

but this isn't working.

I also tried this:

```
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        for word in word_list:
            if word_list[-1].isupper():
                return word_list[-1]
            else:
                return " "
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide a sample and expected output?

Comment: Your second attempt is looking at the last `word_list` element, instead of `word` but are you looking for the last letter in the word or the first letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all, your algorithm would return the first capitlized word, not the last so there needs to be a little change in logic. Also the simplest way to check if word is capitalized is provided:

```
def find_last_capitalised(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        last_cap_word = " "
        for word in word_list:
            if word[0].isupper():
                last_cap_word = word

        return last_cap_word
```

Comment: having a complete brain fart at the moment. why am i putting [0]? it works but can't think why rn i feel dumb haha

Comment: It is because your word is a string and `word[0]` takes the first element (letter, character) in your string. For example if you have `word='puppy'` then `word[0]` would be `p`. `.isupper()` simply checks if the character is uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Others provided you with various method for doing your task. I want to explain why your 1st method do not work as intended:

```
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
if word.rfind(upper):
```

`.rfind` method of `str` is looking for position of last substring `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` inside `word`. I guess that your words do NOT contain such substring, in which case `.rfind` returns `-1`, which according to rules of Python evaluate to `True` (as it is not zero), so it would catch almost any word (it will give `0` or `False` only for words starting with `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` and containing only single `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`)

Comment: appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `reversed`.

**Ex:**

```
def find_last_capitalised(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        for word in reversed(word_list):   #reversed
            if word[0].isupper():
                return word
    return " "
```

Answer (score 1):

You need are returning `" "` at first fail. That's why you don't get expected result.

```py
def find_last_capitalised(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        for word in reversed(word_list):
            if word[0].isupper():
                return word
        return ""
```

However if your file is much bigger, you might want to read file in a reverse order. Which will let you find what you looking for much easier.

```py
import os

def find_last_capitalised(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        wordfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        position = wordfile.tell()
        word = ''
        while position >= 0:
            qfile.seek(position)
            next_char = qfile.read(1)
            if next_char == " ":
                if word[0].isupper():
                    return word
                word = ''
            else:
                word += next_char
            position -= 1
        return ""
```

I suggest using similar approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `reversed` and `is_upper` keywords:

```
def find_last_capitalised(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        word_list = reversed(word_list)
        for word in word_list:
            if word[0].isupper():
                return word

print(find_last_capitalised("demo.txt"))
```

Comment: @ThierryLathuille : I have reversed the list : `word_list = reversed(word_list)`

Comment: Why would you `break` after `return`?

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this.

```py
import re
pattern = "[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+"

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
  for el in reversed(file.readlines()):
    res = re.findall(pattern, el)
    if res:
      print(res[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_last_capitalised(word_list):
    lastCapWord = " "
    for word in word_list:
        print(word)
        if word[0].isupper():
            lastCapWord = word
    print('lastCapWord:', lastCapWord)
    return lastCapWord


word_list = ['this', 'is', 'A', 'test']
find_last_capitalised(word_list)
```

Your algorithm is a little off. It doesn't go through each word in the list, instead it just returns based off the first word it sees. Assuming you make you make your word list into an array, the following code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_last_capitalised(file_name):
with open(file_name) as wordfile:
    text_str = wordfile.read()
    word_list = text_str.split(" ")
    upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for word in reversed(word_list):
        if upper.rfind(word[0]) >= 0:
        return word
    return " "
```

Please try with the above code ... If its not working let me know here.